# node.js "Command not found"

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal

I am attempting to work with node and learning how to write in Javascript. I am currently trying to use my terminal to run a basic "Hello world" js file using node. However, when I attempt to use $node index.js (that's what the file is called). All the terminal responds with is index.js command not found.  I tried to do it with the just the terminal window, I have also tried to run it through the integrated terminal within data studio, so I am unsure of where I went wrong.

Here is a screen shot of my window.
[image]

Comment: Get rid of the $ sign. Type `node index.js`. The $ is usually used to denote a terminal prompt and not part of the command itself.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `$` sign. In web examples, docs use `$` to show that you run it in the command line.

Instead use `node index.js`, or set up a `package.json` file and use `npm start` (`npm start` should contain `node index.js`).

#### Final Clarification (if you didn't understand the above explanation)

Run `node index.js`. `$` is never used, except to show you that the command is used in the command line.

Comment: I would also recommend using `node index.js` in the command line. Eventually, you will want to install dependencies and other npm packages, and while you *can* do that in VSCode, it's a little easier once you get into using commands like `git` and push code to Heroku or other hosting services.